# Migrating rpc webservice to spring-ws ( There should not be any change in client except over-ridding the location URI)

Tags: java, spring-ws

As part of a project i have to migrate an old jax-rpc service to spring-ws. I am new to spring WS so i have first created a basic spring web service which accepts a string and returns a String( old service method also does the same). I also learned how to expose an existing wsdl using . I exposed the wsdl of old rpc service and I am able to access it through Spring.

But now when i try to access the service i get error as

> Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?

Also i noticed that the wsdl for the service i have created  have a schema whereas the old service wsdl doesn't have any input or output schema defined in wsdl. How am i supposed to map the incoming data with the input parameter of endpoint's method input param

old wsdl message description as below

```
<message name="doRequest">
    <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="string" type="partns:string" />
</message>
<message name="doRequestResponse">
    <part xmlns:partns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="result" type="partns:string" />
</message>
```

endpoint method

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "doRequest", namespace = "http://www.varun.com/RetrievalService")
public String retrieveCustomerProfileFromDoReq( String string ) {
     // business processing
    return "Success ::"+ string ;
}
```

Comment: I did some research and found that we need to configure some XSLTs(requestXslt and responseXslt)  to transform the request and response into appropriate format . Still looking if we can handle the same request without making any changes.

Comment: My client doesn't want to spend much time in resolving this issue hence we are keeping the same old service interface and will call the new service internally. BUT I am still curious to know if this problem can be handled in some way

Comment: UPDATE  :: Hummmfff . . . I have successfully migrated the old hax-rpc ws to spring WS . I took below steps 
1) Created a schema for my input\output and mapped it with my service  
2) made sure that all input parameters and exposed method description is same as in old service

Comment: Basically, What i understood after all the research that in order to migrate a web-service ,you have to create a new webservice which exposes same method with same signature.                                                  Do Let me know if anyone need any more information in this regard . . .